# Combining flags in argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have the following subclass that extends `argparse.ArgumentParser` with some helper methods for adding common argument types:

```
import argparse


class ArgParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def add_bool_arg(self, default, help, *flags, **kw):
        """ Add a boolean argument to the parser.
    
        This method adds:
    
            - long flags that store true into the destination
            - long flags with `--no-` prefix that store false into the destination
            - short flags that:
                - store true into the destination if 'True' or 'Yes' is passed as an argument
                - store false into the destination if 'False' or 'No' is passed as an argument
                - toggle the default value if no argument is passed
    
        If `dest` is not explicitly provided, it is inferred from the first long flag or the first short flag if no long flags are passed.
        """
    
        short_flags = [flag for flag in flags if flag[0] == '-' and flag[1] != '-']
        long_flags = [flag for flag in flags if flag[:2] == '--']
        dest = kw.get('dest', long_flags[0] if long_flags else flags[0]).strip('-').replace('-', '_')
    
        no_f = lambda arg: '--no-' + arg.strip('-')
        str_to_bool = lambda s: s.lower() in {'true', 'yes', 't', 'y', '1'}
    
        group = self.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        group.add_argument(*short_flags, dest=dest, nargs='?', default=default, const=not default, type=str_to_bool, help=help, **kw)
        group.add_argument(*long_flags, dest=dest, action='store_true', help=help, **kw)
        group.add_argument(*map(no_f, long_flags), dest=dest, action='store_false', help="do not " + help, **kw)
```

I've also set up a [REPL](https://replit.com/@matedevita/Combining-Argparse-Flags) with this class for easier running.

The `add_bool_arg` method adds flags for a boolean argument with the functionality described in the docstring:

```
ap = ArgParser()
ap.add_bool_arg(True, "default true bool arg", '-t', '--true-arg')
ap.add_bool_arg(False, "default false bool arg", '-f', '--false-arg')
print(ap.parse_args(['-t', 'True']))     # true_arg = True
print(ap.parse_args(['-t', 'False']))    # true_arg = False
print(ap.parse_args(['-t']))             # true_arg = False
print(ap.parse_args(['--true-arg']))     # true_arg = True
print(ap.parse_args(['--no-true-arg']))  # true_arg = False
print(ap.parse_args(['-f', 'False']))    # false_arg = False
print(ap.parse_args(['-f', 'True']))     # false_arg = True
print(ap.parse_args(['-f']))             # false_arg = True
print(ap.parse_args(['--false-arg']))    # false_arg = True
print(ap.parse_args(['--no-false-arg'])) # false_arg = False
```

However, the default boolean arguments in `argparse.ArgumentParser` also allow you to combine flags (for example `-ab` instead of `-a -b`). However my approach does not work like this and only the first flag is processed:

```
ap.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
ap.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
print(ap.parse_args(['-ab']))  # a = True, b = True
print(ap.parse_args(['-tf']))  # true_arg = False, false_arg = True
```

Is there a way to implement this functionality, so that all so-combined flags will be processed (i.e. toggled)? How does argparse even handle this case of splitting combined flags?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of short args, with different `nargs`:

```
In [10]: import argparse    
In [11]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [12]: p.add_argument('-f',nargs='?',default='foo', const='bar');    
In [13]: p.add_argument('-g',action='store_true');    
In [14]: p.add_argument('-e');
```

Sample runs:

```
In [16]: p.parse_args([])
Out[16]: Namespace(f='foo', g=False, e=None)
```

'-f' gets its `const`:

```
In [17]: p.parse_args(['-gf'])
Out[17]: Namespace(f='bar', g=True, e=None)
```

user value for '-f':

```
In [18]: p.parse_args(['-gf2'])
Out[18]: Namespace(f='2', g=True, e=None)
```

The 'e1' is taken as an argument for 'f':

```
In [20]: p.parse_args(['-gfe1'])
Out[20]: Namespace(f='e1', g=True, e=None)
```

In other words, 'f' has to be the last of the short options.  You cannot make it behave like '-g'.

It may be possible to change this behavior with code modification, but the function that handles this is `consume_optional` nested inside `_parse_known_args`.